# Change Tags for Existing Resources in AWS

Tags: aws

I am Trying to change the AWS Tags for the Existing EC2 resources based on Key-Value pair. If Key-value pair matches, add/modify the tag. I am using AWS CLI for this operation

declare -a instance
instance=$(aws ec2 describe-instances | jq ".Reservations[].Instances[].Tags[] | [.Key, .Value]")

This is generating the output as 
[
  "Name",
  "TestCLI2"
]
[
  "Instance",
  "Trial2"
]
[
  "Instance",
  "Trial1"
]
[
  "Name",
  "TestCLI1"
]

Now I want to match for all those instances which has Key="Instance" and Value=["Trial1", "Trial2] should be modified to Trial3

I am trying to use loop but not able to proceed further as how to parse this JSON to check under if statements

for i in "${instance[@]}" # Looping through all the instances

Answer (score 1):

You can use `aws describe` command to get all the ec2 instances that matches the tag with `key="Instance"` and `value=["Trial1", "Trial2"]`.

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --region <yourRegion>   \
   --query Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId] \
   --filters "Name=tag:<tagKey>,Values=<tagValue>" --output text
```

The above command with provide you with instance id of instances matching the filter parameter. In next step you can pass the resource ids to below command.

```
$ aws ec2 create-tags --resources <id1> <id2> ... \
    --tags 'Key=<tagKey>,Value=<newValue>'
```

`Create-tags` command will create new tag if it doesn't exist. If it does then it will update the old tag value with new one.

Using `xargs` you can combine both commands to a single line.

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --region <yourRegion> \
 --query Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId] \
 --filters "Name=tag:<tagKey>,Values=<tagValue>"   \
 --output text| xargs -n1 -I@ aws ec2 create-tags  \
    --resources @ --tags 'Key=<tagKey>,Value=<newValue>'
```

For more info:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-tags.html